# Data Archiving in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any tutorial where I can learn how to create a batch which will
keep on automatically transferring the table contents into a different table, just
to make sure that my main table is maintaining only 30 days old data.
I am using MySQL Workbench to access the database and hence wondering if there is some
way of achieving this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use partitions to avoid having to select/insert/delete the data between tables which is horrendously inefficient. Partitioning can be driven by events as towr link

Comment: Could you elaborate more on Partitioning?